# Recent 'git' seems to be missing CRM/Event/DAO folder

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

First noticed on a Virtual Ubuntu system, now on Windows 7 - I used the 4.6 branch (git checkout upstream/4.6) and no folder was created for CRM/Event/DAO (and no Event.php, Participant.php, ParticipantPayment.php). Other folders (BAO, Form, Page, etc.) are created. Anyone else see this?

Answer (score 3):

A git clone of the CiviCRM source tree is not a complete CiviCRM codebase.

Some CiviCRM code is autogenerated, via a script named `GenCode.php`

See [Github for CiviCRM](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/GitHub+for+CiviCRM#GitHubforCiviCRM-How-To:CheckoutthelatestsourcecodefromGithub) for full instructions.

Comment: I am following the steps here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/GitHub+for+CiviCRM - it didn't make sense that Contact/DAO was fetched, and other data object folders not - thanks for your reply